# Chanah Earned Shmuel Through Niddah, Challah, and Ner Shabbos?

Tags: niddah, candle-lighting, separating-challah, shmuel--the-man, chanah

[Dinonline](https://din.org.il/2021/06/04/%D7%9E%D7%99-%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9C-%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A9-%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%94/) quotes the Hagahos Maimonos (Zeraim, 30) who suggests Chanah earned a son like Shmuel HaNavi because she was so careful with Niddah, Challah, and Ner Shabbos. I can't find this Hagahos Maimonos - can you please locate and share the exact quote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its in the back of Zraim, page 569 in the Frankel edition, not on the rambam itself.

ועל שם זה נקראת צדקת הגדולה חנה ר"ת חל"ה נד"ה הדלק"ה שקיימה ג' מצות אלו כראוי ובכן נתן לה הקב"ה תאות לבה וארשת שפתיה בל מנע.

You can find the whole text quoted [here](https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/12752.15). See also [Hida to Brachot 31a](https://www.sefaria.org/Marit_HaAyin_on_Berakhot.31a.2).

Comment: Thank you - and great find in the Chida!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't looked for the Haghos Maamonis yet, but it is probably based off the gemara in [Brachos 31b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.31b.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> אָמַר רַבִּי יוֹסֵי בְּרַבִּי חֲנִינָא: שָׁלֹשׁ אֲמָתוֹת הַלָּלוּ לָמָּה? — אָמְרָה חַנָּה לִפְנֵי הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא: רִבּוֹנוֹ שֶׁל עוֹלָם, שְׁלֹשָׁה בִּדְקֵי מִיתָה בָּרָאתָ בָּאִשָּׁה, וְאָמְרִי לַהּ: שְׁלֹשָׁה דִּבְקֵי מִיתָה. וְאֵלּוּ הֵן: נִדָּה, וְחַלָּה וְהַדְלָקַת הַנֵּר. כְּלוּם עָבַרְתִּי עַל אַחַת מֵהֶן?!
>
> Rabbi Yosei, son of Rabbi Ḥanina, said: Why are these three maidservants [amatot] cited in the verse? They are cited to teach that Hannah said before the Holy One, Blessed be He: Master of the Universe, You have created three crucibles potentially leading to death in a woman, where she is particularly vulnerable. Alternatively, some say: Master of the Universe, You have created three accelerants of death in a woman. They are mitzvot that, as a rule, pertain to women: Observing the halakhot of a menstruating woman, separating ḥalla from dough, and lighting Shabbat candles. Have I ever violated one of them? Hannah attests to her status as God’s maidservant [ama]. The reference to these three mitzvot is drawn from the etymological similarity between amatekha, your maidservant, and mita, death. (William Davidson translation and notation)

Answer (score 1):

Here’s the relevant text, as it is printed at the end of the  Frankel edition Rambam Sefer Zeraim:

> ועל שם זה נקראת צדקת הגדולה חנה ר״ת ח׳לה נ׳דה ה׳דלקה שקיימה ג׳ מצות אלו כראוי ובכן  נתן לה הקב״ה תאות לבה וארשת שפתיה בל מנע.‏

Comment: This has been answered already?

Comment: @Dov Mordechai and I posted very similar answers at basically the same time